# Are these 2 different definitions of a derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definition

I've recently started learning calculus, and I'm trying to grasp the concept of derivatives. In my textbook, two seemingly different definitions of the derivative are presented:

1. The first definition states:

$$
\frac{d\ f(x)}{dx} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}, \text{ provided limit exists}
\implies
f'(c) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(c+h) - f(c)}{h}, \text{ provided limit exists}
$$

2. Later in the book, another expression is used:

$$
f'(c) = \lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}, \text{ provided limit exists}
$$

I'm struggling to see how these two definitions represent the same concept. Could someone help clarify this for me?

Thank you in advance, and I apologize if this question has been asked before or if there are any formatting errors.

Comment: Draw a picture of the graph of $f$ and a secant line through two points, one at which you want the derivative and the other nearby. You can label the various points and slopes so as to get either form of the definition. So these are just different names for the same entities.

Comment: @Ethan I understand the first one but I have a problem representing second one in the graph. But after reading the answer below I think the first one is just rewriting $x \to a$ as $x = a \pm h$ when $h \to 0$ and vice versa, right?

Comment: Pretty much. Adding to the confusion: in the first one you are finding the derivative at $x$, in the second there's an $x$ but you are finding the derivative at $c$.

Comment: @Ethan but isn't c just a varaible so while $\frac{d\ f(x)}{dx} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}, \text{ provided limit exists}$ defines derative at all values of x in domain of $f$ but $f'(c) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(c+h) - f(c)}{h}, \text{ provided limit exists}$ is specifically at c which should be = $f'(c) = \lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}, \text{ provided limit exists}$, or am I missing something?

Comment: The first expression defines the derivative at all points $x$ in the domain where the limit exists. The second defines the derivative at all points $c$ in the domain where the limit exists. The definitions are identical in meaning. Think about the geometry of the graph, not about whether $x$ or $c$ is a "variable".

Comment: @ethan ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1.) expresses the definition of the derivative as the difference between $f(x+h)$ and $f(x)$ divided by the difference between $x$ and $x+h$ as approaches $h\to 0$, where $h$ is the difference between the points you are trying to find the slope of, which becomes $0$ for instantaneous rates of change.

(2.) approaches this in a different way. Instead of letting the difference approach $0$, $x$ approaches the point at which the derivative is calculated, which is another way of saying the difference between $x$ and the point is $0$. This is a way of saying as two different points become the same point, and you have to find the "slope" between these points. When two points near each other, the difference between them approaches $0$. This is equivalent to $h\to 0$ in (1.). By @Ted's comment, substituting $x=c+h$ changes the limit from $x\to c$ into $h\to 0$, and the rest of (2.) turns into (1.)

Comment: Be direct. In the second, substitute $x=c+h$. And discuss the derivative at $c$ in both cases.

Comment: So the first one is just rewriting $x \to a$ as $x = a \pm h$ when $h \to 0$ and vice versa, right?

Comment: @PrabhasKumar Not $x=c\pm h$. Just $x=c+h$. Yes, $x$ can approach $c$ from either above or below, but that just corresponds to $h$ approaching $0$ from either above or below, respectively.

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember limit $\to c$ means right-hand limit and left-hand limit exists so writing $\pm$ is redundant.